# Bootstrap floating image, text and caption

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm starting to use Twitter Bootstrap 3 and now I have a problem trying to positioning my elements.

I would like to obtain this structure (for xs and sm && for md and lg): http://i59.tinypic.com/2yjrj2e.png

with the code :

```
    <div class="grid col-xs-12 col-md-7">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam posuere, massa non dictum bibendum, leo nulla vestibulum ligula, vel tempor velit enim at ex. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p> 
    </div>

    <div class="grid col-xs-12 col-md-5">
          <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail center-block" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="altText"/></a>
    </div>

    <div class="grid col-xs-12 col-md-5">
          <div class="foot">Some text about the picture</span></div>
    </div>
```

But I cannot place the foot message in the proper place (not floating up ti the free space). Here a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/sr7mp2rc/

Can somebody help me?

Thanks you all

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. All I have done is nested your left column within a md-7 and your right in an md-5.

```
<div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="grid col-md-7">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam posuere, massa non dictum bibendum, leo nulla vestibulum ligula, vel tempor velit enim at ex. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="grid col-xs-12">
              <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail center-block" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="altText"/></a>
        </div>

        <div class="grid col-xs-12">
              <div class="foot">Some text about the picture</span></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your reply, but it's not exactly what I am looking for (in md or lg I would like that foot would be floating next to the pic, please see the img: http://i59.tinypic.com/2yjrj2e.png )

Check the JsFiddle with a big sized result panel : https://jsfiddle.net/sr7mp2rc/3/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="col-md-7">
       
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam posuere, massa non dictum bibendum, leo nulla vestibulum ligula, vel tempor velit enim at ex. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p> 
      <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-12">
    <div class="foot">Some text about the picture</div>
    </div>
    
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="grid col-xs-12">
              <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail center-block" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="altText"/>
        </div>

        <div class="grid hidden-md  col-xs-12">
              <div class="foot">Some text about the picture</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

All other things fine in your code just make your image block label and responsive. Check the CSS

```css
.foot {display:block; background-color:#ffc; color:#0c0; text-align:right; padding:10px; box-sizing:border-box;}

.img-responsive {width:100%; height:auto; display:block; margin-bottom:10px;}
```

Comment: Thanks Opraatnitt, but I would like that the "foot" block be floating next to the pic in wider screens (md & lg context) because many of times I have not much text and the height of img + foot is too much. 

I  have update my jsfiddle with your suggestions: https://jsfiddle.net/sr7mp2rc/4/

Comment: Please read visible and hidden div to fulfill your requirement. I have added the revised html code for your reference.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Thanks